# What does it mean to use the reduce method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing the Free Code Camp series of tutorials and I got the answer right but don't understand a few things ...
Exercise:
Use the reduce method to sum all the values in array and assign it to singleVal.

- singleVal should be equal to the sum of all items in the array variable.
- You should have made use of the reduce method.

  ```
  var array = [4,5,6,7,8];
  var singleVal = 0;
  singleVal = array.reduce(function(previousVal,currentVal){
  return previousVal + currentVal;
  },0);
  ```

I got the answer right by following the example basically.. but I can't understand why there is a comma zero at the end - like what is the point of it?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)? When in doubt, RTFM.

Comment: As Andrew points out, read the various api references out there, like the [MDN Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Parameters) one and see what the arguments are

Comment: The code camp ducumentation or the JavaScript documentation.  Sorry I don't know what you mean.  I'm only 2 months new to JavaScript so pardon my newbie question!

Comment: @Donna I've linked it. MDN is a good source for documentation on almost all JavaScript methods and concepts.

Comment: it's the initial value, which prevent empty arrays to throw an error for missing initial value.

Comment: yes, in the Javascript documentation, it says:
arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])
... so we always have to mention initialValue to not throw an error?

Also thanks for sending the documentation.. is there a good guide on understanding how the documentation works?

Comment: Reduction is a way of obtaining data from a collection of data (avg from array of integers, etc... )

Answer (score 0):

The comma zero at the end denotes the initial value.
The syntax of reduce is `array.reduce(function(total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr), initialValue)`. Mentioning `initialValue` is Optional. A value to be passed to the function as the initial value.

Consider the following example:

```
var array = [4,5,6,7,8];
var singleVal = 0;

//reduce function takes 5 as the initial value then sums up the values of
//the array. 
singleVal = array.reduce(function(previousVal,currentVal){
return previousVal + currentVal;
},5); //5 is passed to the function as the initial value.

console.log(singleVal) //35
```